# Parsing HTML style element using JSON.Parser

Tags: json, html-parsing

I have a json string:

```
var jsonString = "{\"editor1\":\"<b>abc</b>\",\"editor2\":\"<ul><li style=\"text-align: center;\"><b><i><u><strike>abc</strike></u></i></b><br></li></ul>\",\"timepicker1\":\"00:11:01\"}"
```

I need to convert this to a json object. This string contains both html and non html data. I'm using json parser in my js as below:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

but when its parsing the HTML Style bit I'm getting this error:

> Syntax Error: Unexpected token t.

How can I parse an HTML Element using json parser? Should I use another parser?

Answer (score 1):

If it were just an object, the code would look like

```
{
    "editor1":"<b>abc</b>",
    "editor2":"<ul><li style="text-align: center;"><b><i><u><strike>abc</strike></u></i></b><br></li></ul>",
    "timepicker1":"00:11:01"
}
```

Notice the `"..."..."..."`

You need to escape the " characters inside one more time

```
...\"editor2\":\"<ul><li style=\\"text-align: center;\\"><b><i>...
```